# can't resize icon font on Divi footer wordpress

Tags: wordpress, fonts, icons, themes

[image: screenshot]

THIS IS WHAT I HAVE ON THE FOOTER CREDITS on Divi -> Theme customiser -> Footer -> boottom bar -> EDIT FOOTER CREDITS

```
<span class='et-pb-icon' style='font-size:13px;'>&#xe090;</span> 075421199 | <span class='et-pb-icon' style='font-size: 13px; '>&#xe076;</span> email@info.com
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know about DIVI

But you only need to edit your style.css in your theme.

Something like:
.et-pb-icon {font-family:Dashicon;content:'\f125';.....}